# Display Product Name and City where that product sold in largest quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a query to display the product name and city where the product had the highest quantity sold. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (s.city),
  MAX(t.quantity),
  p.Name
FROM [DS715-Cameron-Erwin].dbo.Tb_Transactions AS t,
     [DS715-Cameron-Erwin].dbo.Tb_Product AS p,
     [DS715-Cameron-Erwin].dbo.Tb_Supplier AS s
WHERE p.prod_id = t.prod_id
AND s.Supp_ID = t.Supp_ID
GROUP BY t.Prod_ID,
         p.name,
         s.city
ORDER BY p.name, s.city
```

This is giving me the highest quantity sold for each product in each city.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgb42.png)

From the screenshot there are multiple records for each product (Airplane, Auto, Boat...). I'm trying to get a single record for each product where ever the highest quantity was purchased.
So, the top record would only show for Airplane because the most orders were from there.

Comment: Post sample data and desired output based on that sample data - I'm not entirely sure that I understood your question as well as I initially thought that I did.

Comment: Added a screenshot with the output when running the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` functionality to order by the quantity and then select the one with the biggest quantity over each product.

```
SELECT
  city,
  quantity,
  name
FROM  
(

    SELECT  S.city,
            T.quantity,
            P.name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER
              ( PARTITION BY
                P.name
                ORDER BY t.Quantity DESC
              ) as RowNum
    FROM
            Tb_Transactions T
                INNER JOIN
            Tb_Product P
                ON
              P.prod_id = T.prod_id
                INNER JOIN
            Tb_Supplier S
                ON
              S.supp_id = T.supp_id
 ) a
 WHERE
     RowNum = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/628458/5

[image]

Comment: If I wanted to change S.City to S.Name how would that look? I keep getting an error saying that "Name" has been specified multiple times.

Comment: @CameronErwin is `S.Name` the name of the supplier? That's a good reason to use unique field names (even across tables). You'll need to create an alias as in `S.Name AS SupplierName`.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would use a CTE (also I would use the explicit INNER JOIN syntax):

```
;With CTE
As
(
    Select
        s.city
        , t.quantity
        , p.Name  
        , Row_Number Over (Partition By P.Name, s.city Order By t.Quantity Desc) as RN
    From [DS715-Cameron-Erwin].dbo.Tb_Transactions as t 
        Inner Join [DS715-Cameron-Erwin].dbo.Tb_Product as p
            On p.prod_id = t.prod_id
        Inner Join [DS715-Cameron-Erwin].dbo.Tb_Supplier as s
            On s.Supp_ID = t.Supp_ID
)
Select
    city
    , quantity
    , Name
From CTE
Where RN = 1
```

Comment: This looks to be on point, however, I'm trying to stay with the current format for my code as I don't know what CTE is. Thanks for the input!

Comment: If you don't know what CTE (common table Expression) is.. then it's about time you did.. makes SQL so much easier to write

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it I'm not sure that this is correct - see my comment on your initial question, @CameronErwin